# How to supplement the result set with dates for Saturday and Sunday when they are not in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table with the prices of goods from different sellers for different dates.
The same item can be sold by different sellers. There is only one entry per date for one item for one seller.

**Some dates may be missing for all items**

| id_seller | id_item | price | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 2022-07-08 |
| 2 | 1 | 11 | 2022-07-08 |
| 1 | 2 | 20 | 2022-07-08 |
| 2 | 2 | 19 | 2022-07-08 |
| 1 | 1 | 12 | 2022-07-11 |
| 2 | 1 | 13 | 2022-07-11 |
| 1 | 2 | 22 | 2022-07-11 |
| 2 | 2 | 21 | 2022-07-11 |

As you can see,  this table has no rows for 2022-07-09 and 2022-07-10.

I need to get the average price of an item for all sellers each of the 7 days back from the specified date, including missing dates (for these days in the column price will be NULL).

The result I need should look like this

| id_item | avg_price | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.5 | 2022-07-08 |
| 2 | 19.5 | 2022-07-08 |
| 1 | NULL | 2022-07-09 |
| 2 | NULL | 2022-07-09 |
| 1 | NULL | 2022-07-10 |
| 2 | NULL | 2022-07-10 |
| 1 | 12.5 | 2022-07-11 |
| 2 | 21.5 | 2022-07-11 |

Can it be done by SQL query in MySQL 8.0 **without using stored procedures** ?

Comment: You need a calendar table containing all dates which you want to appear in the report.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Don't see you here at this time... ever.

Comment: @TheImpaler Great observation.  I am visiting family in New York right now.  It is 5am in Singapore (where I live), hence you never see me at this time.